# Lodash `get` method behaving inconsistently in between versions in Vue app

Tags: javascript, vue.js, lodash

Something seems to have changed with the behavior of the `get` method in lodash. I just updated my version of lodash from `3.10.1` to `4.17.15`. I'm using lodash within a Vue.js application. In the newer version, It seems that the `get` method no longer returns the same value for the same object.

I have this line within my Vue component:

```
import _ from 'lodash';

export default {
    props: ['price'],

    data () {
        console.log(this.price.rrp_without_tax.value, _.get(this.price, 'rrp_without_tax.value'))
    }
};
```

In the newer version I get undefined even though the value exists. In the older version I get the value. This is the output when the exact same code is run only changing the installed version of lodash:

```
lodash@3.10.1
129.99 129.99

lodash@4.17.15
129.99 undefined
```

The 'price' object is a reactive Vue object, which means it has getters for its properties. I wonder if that is partly causing the problem?

I've posted this on Github has an issue, but wanted to ask here to see if anyone had other ideas what might be causing this strange behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Whoops, found the problem. It had to do with webpack using a lodash plugin and alias. It was mapping my imports to the wrong files.